# CakePHP: How do I change page title from helper?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm using a helper for static pages to add a part to the title on every page.
Currently I have the following code at the top of every static page:

```
<?php $this->set('title_for_layout', $title->output('Nyheter')); ?>
```

The purpose of $title->output is to append " :: MY WEB SITE NAME".
This works fine, but for simplicity I would rather just call:

```
$title->title('Nyheter');
```

At the top of every page to set the title. The problem is that I can't call $this->set() from within the helper. Is there a way to something like this or am I completely on the wrong path here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the risk of being too obvious, why do you need the helper? I usually include this kind of title like:

```
<title><?php echo $title_for_layout . ' :: MY WEB SITE NAME' ?></title>
```

Plug this right into the layout and you have dynamic and static components the render nicely. For an added twist, you can filter out the " :: " if no `$title_for_layout` value exists. Then all you have to worry about is setting the dynamic portion on any page that needs it.

Comment: Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes to see the obvious. We've all had those moments. :-)